# Equally space unknown number of images horizontally

Tags: jquery, equals, centering

However many dots are added, I want them spaced equally across a line, and not go over the width of the line.
Here is what I have so far, which works ok until too many images are added, then they go over.

```
var count = $('#dots img').length;
var dotW = $('.dot').width();
var line = $('#line').width();

var x = count * dotW;
var y = line - x;
var z = y / (count + 1);

$('.dot').css('margin-left', z);
```

Check out the jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/kirkr/2L9eg/
Copy and paste the image tag to test more.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is whitespace between the images. Use this CSS:

```
#dots {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

And it works fine.

**Edit:**

Played around with it a bit. You can replace the divs with the images if you want. Be sure to remove as much whitespace as possible from the images.

http://jsfiddle.net/2L9eg/6/

Comment: This was a slight improvement, however on my site, it still goes over the width of the line when I add 30+ images. This is for an application and the dots represent pages (which I'm not sure how many there will be).

Comment: sorry jimjimmy, the page is local, I don't have access to the ftp at work. Bummer, I know.

Comment: The problem is that the margin goes into negatives pulling the image outside of the element.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have to use Internet Explorer 7 Standards. even with the bug fix { zoom:1; *display:inline } they are making rows. Is there hope in this working in ie7? And thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Could try doing `var z = Math.floor(y / (count));`. Wouldn't work as well on better browsers but may fix IE. IE doesn't like jsFiddle in ie7standards mode for some reason or I would test it. I don't really develop for IE so I can't really help much more. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are fine, it's the white space in the HTML that's causing more space than expected.

[Here's a version without whitespace between the`img` tags](http://jsfiddle.net/2L9eg/3/).

Answer (score -1):

Just apply a css class with the desired property (probably margin) after the page loads every "dot". IE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dot").css("margin-right","10px");
});
```

Comment: I tried dividing the result by two and setting that variable to bot right and left margin, but no luck